# Cygwin Terminal and zsh strange characters used in username

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin, zsh

Hi I've recently installed zsh using cygwin on my Windows machince but when I type zsh to start this I get the following:

```
 GG@GG-PC ~
$ zsh
\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$
```

On my mac I am using iTerm2 and this is so much easier to setup on here. Also I am having trouble in setting up the aliases and this is becauses its not setup properly in terms of config file where I can set this up in a separate file.

Any ideas how I can resolve?

Comment: you're using the wrong terminal emulation, probably.

Comment: @marcb how can I investigate and resolvE?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like `zsh` is inheriting the value of `PS1` from the previous shell. The `PS1` environment variable sets the shell prompt, and `zsh` used a different format for prompt substitutions than other shells. Try entering the following command after you start `zsh`:

```
PS1=$'%{\e]0;%d\a%}\n%F{green}%n@%m %F{yellow}%d%f\n%# '
```

If that works, add that line to your `~/.zshrc` file.

That's also probably a good place to put your aliases.

Comment: I tried this and, while it works to fix the user name, it does something with the keyboard to make it unusable.  I had to log out and back in to fix it.  (Windows 10 on HP Elitebook).

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue because you launch **zsh** from **bash** actually and not **cygwin**.

One thing you can do is to launch **zsh** as the starting shell of **mintty** *(the window that wraps your shell)*

Create a shortcut with this inside: 
`c:\<cygwin-folder>\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico /usr/bin/zsh --login -`

Answer (score -1):

Yo need to update .zshrc with your required theme and then

```
source .zshrc
```